# Entity Framework using BeginTransaction()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to implement Entity Framework in my application and i should be able to commit and rollback the changes manually.

First time when i execute the update statement it updates the table successfully and i am able to rollback the changes. **This is correct**

But second time when i execute the update statement, it updates the table successfully and also commits the changes. So I am unable to rollback manually. **This is wrong**

Please let me know why it is happening and how to solve this issue.

The below code is just sample to reproduce my problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data;

namespace EFTest
{
    public class DBOperations
    {
        NorthwindEntities NorthwindContext;
        DbTransaction transObject;

        public DBOperations()
        {
        }

        public void ConnectDB()
        {
            try
            {
                if (NorthwindContext == null)
                {
                    NorthwindContext = new NorthwindEntities();
                    if (NorthwindContext != null && NorthwindContext.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        NorthwindContext.Connection.Open();
                        transObject = NorthwindContext.Connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Database Error " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public int disconnect()
        {
            if (NorthwindContext != null && transObject != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    transObject.Rollback();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
                transObject.Dispose();
                NorthwindContext.Connection.Close();
                NorthwindContext.Dispose();
            }

            return 0;
        }

        public void CommitTransaction()
        {
            if (NorthwindContext != null && transObject != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    transObject.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
        }

        public void RollbackTransaction()
        {
            if (NorthwindContext != null && transObject != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    transObject.Rollback();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
        }

        public int UpdateDB()
        {
            int _returnVal = 0;


            try
            {
                NorthwindContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("UPDATE Orders SET OrderDate = GETDATE() WHERE OrderID = '10248'");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Database Error " + ex.Message);
            }

            return _returnVal;
        }
    }

    public class program
    {
        public program()
        {
            //Establishing the connection.
            DBOperations _DBOperations = new DBOperations();
            _DBOperations.ConnectDB();

            //Update the datebase
            _DBOperations.UpdateDB();                           //Update the database but it doesn't commit the changes.                       

            //Issue Rollback to rollback the transaction.
            _DBOperations.RollbackTransaction();                //Successfully Rollbacks the database changes.


            //Again Update the datebase
            _DBOperations.UpdateDB();                           //Update the database it commits the changes. 

            //Issue Rollback to rollback the transaction.
            _DBOperations.RollbackTransaction();                //Rollback fails.

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)

Comment: @GertArnold Yes i thought about it but how to manually commit or rollback using TransactionScope?

Comment: To commit, you only have to `Complete()` a transaction scope. If you dispose a TS without completing it rolls back.

Comment: Question: do you only execute a store command?

Comment: @GertArnold No. I am using Context.SaveChanges() also but in one scenario I am using store command just to check whether a particular row is locked in a table. I am new to the EntityframeWork, So I am trying to build best logic. I think it is good have more than one instance of context, may be one context per screen. Is it correct? please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign new transaction after commit or rollback of transaction .

```
public program()
{
    //Establishing the connection.
    DBOperations _DBOperations = new DBOperations();
    _DBOperations.ConnectDB();

    //Update the datebase
    _DBOperations.UpdateDB();    //Update the database but it doesn't commit the changes.

    //Issue Rollback to rollback the transaction.
    _DBOperations.RollbackTransaction();    //Successfully Rollbacks the database changes.

    _DBOperations.ConnectDB(); //you need to assign new transaction because your last 
                               //transaction is over when you commit or roll back 

    _DBOperations.UpdateDB();    //Update the database it commits the changes.

    //Issue Rollback to rollback the transaction.
    _DBOperations.RollbackTransaction();    //Rollback fails.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback... So there is no possibility that i can use the same transaction object through out despite the number of commits and rollbacks... Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

With [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) Your DbOperations could look like this:

```
public class DBOperations : IDisposable
{
    NorthwindEntities _context;
    private TransactionScope _transactionScope;

    public DBOperations()
    {
        this.Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        try
        {
            this.Dispose();
            this._transactionScope = new TransactionScope();
            this._context = new NorthwindEntities();
            // no need to open connection. Let EF manage that.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Database Error " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void RollbackTransaction()
    {
            try
            {
                this._transactionScope.Dispose();
                this._transactionScope = null;
                this.Dispose();
                this.Initialize();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // TODO
            }
    }

    public int UpdateDB()
    {
        int _returnVal = 0;
        try
        {
            this._context.ExecuteStoreCommand("UPDATE Orders SET OrderDate = GETDATE() WHERE OrderID = '10248'");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Database Error " + ex.Message);
        }
        return _returnVal;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this._transactionScope != null)
        {
            this._transactionScope.Complete();
            this._transactionScope.Dispose();
        }
        if (this._context != null) this._context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And the program:

```
public class program
{
    public program()
    {
        using (DBOperations dbOperations = new DBOperations())
        {
            dbOperations.UpdateDB(); // Update the database no commit.

            dbOperations.RollbackTransaction(); // Rollback.

            dbOperations.UpdateDB(); // Update the database no commit.

            dbOperations.RollbackTransaction(); // Rollback.
        } // Commit on Dispose.
    }
}
```

A connection that is opened within the scope of a TransactionScope automatically enlists in the transaction. The transaction is *only* committed by calling `Commplete()`. Disposing or unhandled exceptions will cause a rollback.

If you do more than just a store command, as in changing objects and relying on the context's change tracking, you may to implement a retry mechanism in stead of just discarding the context and the changes.

Comment: No. I am using Context.SaveChanges() also but in one scenario I am using store command just to check whether a particular row is locked in a table. I am new to the EntityframeWork, So I am trying to build best logic. I think it is good have more than one instance of context, may be one context per screen. Is it correct? please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Yes, context instances come and go. They should be short-lived. Like one per web request or one per service call. One per screen in a Windows application may work (because often lazy loading can happen) but even then it is better to load what you need and then dispose.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you feedback. It really helps me in understanding EF. But I have lot of questions regarding EF. Will you help me?

Comment: Just ask your questions here at SO and anyone, including me, will see if they help. Check if there are no answers yet, though.